# Search outlook emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am thoroughly frustrated with the Outlook2010 search capabilities. I am a GMAIL fanatic and I am very used to typing a few sentences in the body of an email and searching instantly.

What are the best outlook search tools out there?

I know of Xobni which creates large indexes and sometimes slows the system down. It tries to be "social" in ranking contacts etc. These are things I dont need or care about. I just need the most efficient searching system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't shoot me for asking, but has the indexing finished on Outlook -  I typically only have issues during the indexing process. When you click on the search bar in Outlook, make sure the ribbon has "All Mail Items selected" - it should be instant.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the same issue. Its not just a indexing thing...gmail search is just smarter.

Answer (score 1):

Try CloudMagic (https://cloudmagic.com/)
Alternatively, our email client has pretty awesome relevance-based search on Exchange (using elasticsearch), but it's still closed to the public. If you want to test it out, let me know.